# bootstrap and html not showing intended page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i am having problem with bootstrap and html not showing the intended page that i want , i will try to explain what i want briefly as this is my first ever post here

1.that the google fonts was not showing the fonts right

2.i tried to code the left div to make the paragraph in a box but i couldn't

[supposed to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGkhN.png)

instead i coded like the course that i am coding with and this is my code below in bootstrap and html and css

since i implemented the container fluid from bootstrap, the problems started to appear

maybe my eyes failing me and i cannot see the problem or maybe bootsrtap default values changed

here is the a compressed file with all the images and files needed if you wanted to try it out on your computer
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1582iahENUldh-xF-uNg1xaK7toKEcOqP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TinDog</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--google font not working here-->!<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One|Montserrat|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>



  <section id="title">


    <!-- Nav Bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">

        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>

    </nav>



    <!-- Title -->
    <!--the problem might be here-->!
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h1>Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
          <button type="button">Download</button>
          <button type="button">Download</button>



        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Features -->

  <section id="features">

    <h3>Easy to use.</h3>
    <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>

    <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
    <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>

    <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
    <p>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>

  </section>


  <!-- Testimonials -->

  <section id="testimonials">

    <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
    <img src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
    <em>Pebbles, New York</em>

    <!-- <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
    <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
    <em>Beverly, Illinois</em> -->

  </section>


  <!-- Press -->

  <section id="press">
    <img src="images/techcrunch.png" alt="tc-logo">
    <img src="images/tnw.png" alt="tnw-logo">
    <img src="images/bizinsider.png" alt="biz-insider-logo">
    <img src="images/mashable.png" alt="mashable-logo">

  </section>


  <!-- Pricing -->

  <section id="pricing">

    <h2>A Plan for Every Dog's Needs</h2>
    <p>Simple and affordable price plans for your and your dog.</p>


    <h3>Chihuahua</h3>
    <h2>Free</h2>
    <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
    <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
    <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
    <button type="button">Sign Up</button>


    <h3>Labrador</h3>
    <h2>$49 / mo</h2>
    <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
    <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
    <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
    <button type="button">Sign Up</button>


    <h3>Mastiff</h3>
    <h2>$99 / mo</h2>
    <p>Pirority Listing</p>
    <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
    <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
    <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
    <button type="button">Sign Up</button>

  </section>


  <!-- Call to Action -->

  <section id="cta">

    <h3>Find the True Love of Your Dog's Life Today.</h3>
    <button type="button">Download</button>
    <button type="button">Download</button>

  </section>


  <!-- Footer -->

  <footer id="footer">

    <p>© Copyright 2018 TinDog</p>

  </footer>


</body>

</html>
```

css:

```
#title{
  background-color: #ff4c68;
}

h1{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.container-fluid{
  padding: 3% 15%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always include custom stylesheet (style.css) at the end of head section like this

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TinDog</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One|Montserrat|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
```

By doing this everything works fine. For font make sure that you install "Montserrat" font on your system or include google font link in your files either index.html or style.css. For heading make `font-size: 1.5rem` to `font-size:3.5rem` and `font-weight:normal` to `font-weight:bold` then it gives the same result as you want.

Comment: that was it , i just wanted to ask , why should the style sheet be on the end of the head section , is there a specific reason for this to happen , if you know more information about this or the name if this problem on the internet , or refer me to reading stuff to learn on this matter , as it came to my mind that i wanted to maybe edit the ,y post title maybe to a more relative title to people wanted to find it in the future

Comment: The reason behind including custom stylesheet at the end of the head section is that the browser renders the webpage line by line and execute the page accordingly. For example, I include these links in my head section `<link href="bootstrap.min.css"> <link href="style.css">`. So, the browser first executes a bootstrap file then style.css file. If I include style.css file before the bootstrap.min.css file then my custom styles just override by bootstrap.min.css file styles as the browser renders the bootstrap file later.

Comment: okay , i also noticed just now that the font also not working right or not showing the inteded fonts from google fonts < is that also related some how with this ?

because i got my self confused in which is the right order

Comment: The font is not related to the order of links. You can place it anywhere in between the head section. You can also import fonts in style.css file. If you want to place it in index.html file than include these lines `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">`. If you want to include fonts in style.css file then use this one `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');`